# Is there a diagnostic term for a person who impulsively keeps secrets?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, terminology, compulsive

Almost like an addiction, similar to the way a pyromaniac feels about fire or burning...  I don't know if there's even a word for this, seeing as it's not a common experience, but if there is, it would probably end with "maniac"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list of [impulse control disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_control_disorder) described in the DSM.

As can be seen from the list, many "official" names of impulsive disorders do not end in mania - eg, pathological gambling, sexual compulsion, compulsive buying, and the one most closely related to what is described in the question: [Pathological lying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_lying).  And if it doesn't fit in the latter category, then:

> Disorders characterized by impulsivity that were not categorized
>   elsewhere in the DSM-IV-TR were also included in the category
>   "Impulse-control disorders not elsewhere classified".